# vb.net iterate through request.form arrays

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have form data submitted to my page like this

```
data[user][0][id] = 1
data[user][0][firstname] = "John"
data[user][0][lastname] = "Doe"
data[user][1][id] = 2
data[user][1][firstname] = "Karen"
data[user][1][lastname] = "Smith"
```

What's the best way to iterate through these values?

Comment: [For...Next Statement?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx). Anyway, I can't see how you can iterate through these values because you constantly change their *values*.

Comment: How can I reach the keys? `For i = 0 To ??.Length`